# One instance with multple GPUs or multiple instances with one GPU

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, pytorch, gpu

I am running multiple models using GPUs and all jobs combined can be run on 4 GPUs, for example. Multiple jobs can be run on the same GPU since the GPU memory can handle it.

Is it a better idea to spin up a powerful instance with all 4 GPUs as part of it and run all the jobs on one instance? Or should I go the route of having multiple instances with 1 GPU on each?

There are a few factors I'm thinking of:

- Latency of reading files. Having a local disk on one machine should be faster latency wise, but it would be a quite a few reads from one source. Would this cause any issues?
- I would need quite a few vCPU and a lot of memory to scale the IOPS since GPC scales IOPS that way, apparently. What is the best way to approach this? If anyone has any more on this, would appreciate pointers.
- If in the future I need to downgrade to save costs/downgrade performance, I could simple stop the instance and change my specs.
- Having everything on one machine would be easier to work with. I know in production I would want a more distributed approach, but this is strictly experimentation.

Those are my main thoughts. Am I missing something? Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: Are you using GCP? Which product?

Comment: @R.Esteves That's right, using GCP. I'm using the compute VM's, testing different persistent disks such as SSD and even local SSD and their GPUs that they provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with one machine with multiple GPUs. Just assigned the jobs to the different GPUs to make the memory work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you'll take a look here if you want to run multiple tasks on the same [GPU](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/MPS-(EXPERIMENTAL)).

Basically when using several tasks (different processes or containers) on the same GPU, it won't be efficient due to some kind on context switching.
You'll need the latest nvidia hardware to test it.